# How to feed training set labels into Keras LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, lstm

I’m implementing an `LSTM` with `Keras` and I know that I have to reshape the training dataset in a 3D object. Basically I have a dataset of shape `(300000, 839)`and I reshape it as `(100000, 3, 839)` because I want a timestep of 3. The question is: how could I treat the training set labels? Have I to reshape also them? if I reshape the labels to `100000`, I don't truncate `200000` labels, since the starting number of labels is `300000`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your approch so far is not exactly right. Assuming you want to use the [many to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras) approcah, the way you do it is as follows:

You have a dataset like this:

[image]

And you prepare your data in a way like this:

[image]

[Source](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/10/doing-multivariate-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks.html)

For a timestep of 3, you discard the first 2 occurrences of your labels and use $y_{3}$ for the inputs $\{x_1, x_2,x_3\}$.

Next you don't start in $x_4$. Instead you use the next three-item slice $\{x_2, x_3, x_4\}$ with the training label $y_4$.

You continue this way until the last imput $\{x_{n-2}, x_{n-1}, x_{n}\}$ to predict $y_n$. If you have $n=30000$ samples, you can generate up to $n-2$ (29998) training samples for your model following this logic.

Comment: ’s thank you for the asnwer. So my model predictions will be 29998 labels?

Comment: As fas as I understand what you want to do, yes

Comment: my task is to predict the correct words order given an unordered sentence. So, my dataset is a list of words (I could reshape the dataset in a 3D shape into a set of sentence, where each matrix of data is the set of words of the sentence). Optimally I would predict each word label, but if  I have to truncate only the first 3 labels of the dataset (with ```timesteps=3```) I think that is not a problem for the learning. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reshape the labels. The labels in an LSTM can be one dimension. Only the array holding the x values needs to be reshaped.